# Identifying dynamically created checkboxes

Tags: asp.net, xml

I have a web page where a checkboxlist is created dynamically from a XML file.

The XML looks like this:

```
<properties>
   <property id="abc" value="150" text="mumbo jumbo" />
   <property id="def" value="150" text="more mumbo jumbo" />
```

I am creating my checkboxlist like this:

```
if (checkBoxes.Count > 0)
{
    chkServices.DataSource = checkBoxes;
    chkServices.DataTextField = "text";
    chkServices.DataValueField = "value";
    chkServices.DataBind();
}
```

I would like to get the id going with those individual checkboxes but can't seem to figure it out.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the rendered html for the checkbox, do you able to see the id there?

Comment: Oh, I meant the id from the xml file, like "abc".. etc. I would like a way to get this one hanging on to the elements.. if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this after DataBind:

```
foreach (ListItem c in chkServices.Items)
{
    c.Attributes.Add("ID", "abc");
}
```

Comment: might work, if I can keep some order of the id's from the xml and match them to the right component in the list, thanks

Comment: that should be easy to achieve. `for(int i = 0; i < chkServices.Items.Count; i++){ chkServices.Items[i].Attributes.Add("ID", checkBoxes[i].id); }`

Comment: yep, except that .net loves the weird ids of the type "MainContent_chkServices_0" so much that it adds a <span> tag with my id instead of swapping the checkbox one. Well, at least they are there, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you create a CheckboxList control and give it an ID of "test" then it should give the checkboxes in the list an ID in the format of parentid + _ + itemindex, so "test_0", "test_1", "test_2" etc.

Just remember that to get the ID for each checkbox for the purpose of using it in javascript you'll probably need to use CheckboxList.ClientID + _ + itemindex.

Comment: Nice solution, but I would need the individual id's from the xml file